# Application failed to load application.yml file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, junit, yaml

I am writting junit test cases, strange thing happening
I have two databases

- 1) **campaign** (Application level)
     2) **test**  (Testing level)

**My application structure is**

```
    App
    --> src/main/java
    --> src/main/resource
        application.yml

    --> src/test/java
        src/test/resource
        application.yml
```

When i ran **Application** and it loads **src/main/resource application.yml** file and store into memory and points to **campaign** db that works fine.
When i run **Junit test cases** application load again **src/main/resource application.yml** rather loading **src/test/resource application.yml**

When i forcefully **run test cases** then application points to **test** database
and when i stop server and re-again run application it again points to **test** database instead of **campaign** database.

**application.yml for (src/main/resources) or (src/test/resources)**

```
spring:
   profiles.active: local
   aop.proxy-target-class: true

---
spring:
  profiles: local

campaignDB:
  driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/campaign
  username: root
  password: Admin@123

juintDB:
  driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
  username: root
  password: Admin@123
```

**Testing level configuration**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestDbConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Profile("local")
    public DataSource testDbdatasource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource datasource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("juintDB.driverClassName"));
        datasource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("juintDB.url"));
        datasource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("juintDB.username"));
        datasource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("juintDB.password"));
        return datasource;
    }
}
```

**Application level configuration**

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(datasource());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpa);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com.brighttalk.campaign.model");

    Map<String, String> jpaSchema = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jpaSchema.put("hibernate.default_schema",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.default_schema"));

    jpaSchema.put("hibernate.dialect",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    jpaSchema.put("hibernate.format_sql",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    jpaSchema.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    jpaSchema.put("hibernate.show_sql",
            env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

    emf.setJpaPropertyMap(Collections.singletonMap(
            "javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none"));
    emf.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaSchema);
    return emf;
}
```

I am expecting when i test cases it should points to test database.
and when i run Application it should points to campaign database.

Answer (score 1):

Application properties are expected to be located under the main resource directory, so the behavior you're experiencing is normal.

To achieve what you're trying to do, you need to create a profile specific application properties, either by:

1. Having a separate file for each profile (for instance `application-test.yml` for a profile named `test`) and add it in the same directory.
2. Or as you did above add separate profile specific properties in the same `application.yml` file.

Then you'll need to run your integration tests with active profile `test`, and spring boot then will pick up the properties specific to this profile.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    ....
}
```

If you do not specify and active profile then the active profile will be `default` which means spring boot will load the default properties.

Comment: Ahmed Abdelhady Thank for reply , I went with point 1 , Created application-test.yml file under src/test/resources folder , while running test cases it only points to src/main/resources application file rather then test application-test.yml , As both files have almost same configuration so working fine as expected but still selecting wrong application.yml

Comment: all application properties files should be located under `src/main/resources` if you want spring boot to detect and load them with extra configuration, regardless of the fact that you plan to use them for test or actual business logic

Comment: also no need for any of the configuration you have for tests, just use the datasource properties from spring boot properties instead of adding your custom datasource properties and spring boot will automatically create the datasource bean for you.